# list iteration changes original list to None

Tags: python, csv, file-io, pandas

I am reading a csv file and then doing some filtering:

```
csv_chunks = pandas.read_csv(filepath, sep = DELIMITER,skiprows = 2, chunksize = 1000, converters = {"A": str, "B": str})

csv_chunks_new = [chunk[(chunk["A"] + chunk["B"]).isin(acids.tolist())]
          for chunk in csv_chunks]
```

The weird thing is, when I now try to turn csv_chunks into a dataframe

```
df = pandas.concat(chunk for chunk in csv_chunks)
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception: All objects passed were None
```

So although I am re-assigning the filtered result to a new object (csv_chunks_new), it seems to change csv_chunks as well. Any ideas what might be going on?

Thanks,
Anne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csv_chunks` is not a list, it is itself an iterator. By looping over all elements you've exhausted that iterator. It no longer returns elements when you loop over it *again*, and `pandas.concat()` complains because it is passed an empty sequence.

Simply recreate the object:

```
csv_chunks = pandas.read_csv(filepath, sep = DELIMITER,skiprows = 2, chunksize = 1000, converters = {"A": str, "B": str})
```

which returns a fresh iterator.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martijn. Just to make sure I understand this - when is the file being read? At the point where I create the iterator, or when the iterator is used?

Comment: When the iterator is used, *presumably*; it is theoretically possible `pandas.read_csv()` opens the file, reads all data into memory then yields that data as you loop over the iterator, but that is unlikely and would be very inefficient.

Comment: @Anne: Looking over the [source code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/parsers.py), and seeing you specified a chunk size, the conclusion is that the file is being read as the iterator is used.